# table pagination in pure javascript but if number is not working properly?

Tags: javascript, html

I have create a table with pagination is every thing is fine and good but only one issue i have face and not finding any good solution can u please any body solve this and let us know where is the error int this code .

Issue is

1. if i click to s.no then shorting is not fine.

i used to this function for shorting **_tableCustomFun.sortTable**

```
var tb = table.tBodies[0], // use `<tbody>` to ignore `<thead>` and `<tfoot>` rows
        tr = Array.prototype.slice.call(tb.rows, 0), // put rows into array
        i;
    reverse = -((+reverse) || -1);
    tr = tr.sort(function (a, b) { // sort rows
        return reverse // `-1 *` if want opposite order
            * (a.cells[col].textContent.trim() // using `.textContent.trim()` for test
                .localeCompare(b.cells[col].textContent.trim())
               );
    });
    for(i = 0; i < tr.length; ++i) tb.appendChild(tr[i]); // append each row in order
```

my code is below .

```js
myTableObjData = {
  'head':['s.no', 'name', 'per%', 'price'],
  'body': [
          [1,'rohit', '9%', 23],
          [10,'rohit azad', '19%', 230],
          [8,'rohit', '39%', 111],
      ]
}


var _tableCustomFun = {
    create_sample_table: function(parentNode, head, body, foot, data) {
        if (typeof head == "undefined") {head = true;}
        if (typeof body == "undefined") {body = true;}
        if (typeof foot == "undefined") {foot = true;}
        data = myTableObjData;
        
        var table = document.createElement("table");
        var tr, th, td;
        // header
        tr = document.createElement("tr");
        var headers = data.head || [];
        for (var i=0;i<headers.length;i++) {
            th = document.createElement("th");
            span = document.createElement("span");
            span.innerHTML = headers[i];
            th.appendChild(span);
            tr.appendChild(th);
        }
        if (head) {
            var thead = document.createElement("thead");
            thead.appendChild(tr);
            table.appendChild(thead);
        } else {
            table.appendChild(tr);
        }
        // end header
    
        // body
        var table_body = data.body || [];
        if (body) {
            var tbody = document.createElement("tbody");
        }
        for (var i=0;i<table_body.length;i++) {
            tr = document.createElement("tr");
            for (var j=0;j<table_body[i].length;j++) {
                td = document.createElement("td");
                td.innerHTML = table_body[i][j];
                tr.appendChild(td);
            }
            if (body) {
                tbody.appendChild(tr);
            } else {
                table.appendChild(tr);
            }
        }
        if (body) {
            table.appendChild(tbody);
        }
        // end body
    
        if (parentNode) {
            parentNode.innerHTML = "";
            parentNode.appendChild(table);
        }
        //return table;
    },
    paginator: function(config) {
        // throw errors if insufficient parameters were given
        if (typeof config != "object")
            throw "Paginator was expecting a config object!";
        if (typeof config.get_rows != "function" && !(config.table instanceof Element))
            throw "Paginator was expecting a table or get_row function!";
    
        // get/set if things are disabled
        if (typeof config.disable == "undefined") {
            config.disable = false;
        }
    
        // get/make an element for storing the page numbers in
        var box;
        if (!(config.box instanceof Element)) {
            config.box = document.createElement("div");
        }
        box = config.box;
    
        // get/make function for getting table's rows
        if (typeof config.get_rows != "function") {
            config.get_rows = function () {
                var table = config.table
                var tbody = table.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0]||table;
    
                // get all the possible rows for paging
                // exclude any rows that are just headers or empty
                children = tbody.children;
                var trs = [];
                for (var i=0;i<children.length;i++) {
                    if (children[i].nodeType = "tr") {
                        if (children[i].getElementsByTagName("td").length > 0) {
                            trs.push(children[i]);
                        }
                    }
                }
    
                return trs;
            }
        }
        var get_rows = config.get_rows;
        var trs = get_rows();
    
        // get/set rows per page
        if (typeof config.rows_per_page == "undefined") {
            var selects = box.getElementsByTagName("select");
            if (typeof selects != "undefined" && (selects.length > 0 && typeof selects[0].selectedIndex != "undefined")) {
                config.rows_per_page = selects[0].options[selects[0].selectedIndex].value;
            } else {
                config.rows_per_page = 150;
            }
        }
        var rows_per_page = config.rows_per_page;
    
        // get/set current page
        if (typeof config.page == "undefined") {
            config.page = 1;
        }
        var page = config.page;
    
        // get page count
        var pages = (rows_per_page > 0)? Math.ceil(trs.length / rows_per_page):1;
    
        // check that page and page count are sensible values
        if (pages < 1) {
            pages = 1;
        }
        if (page > pages) {
            page = pages;
        }
        if (page < 1) {
            page = 1;
        }
        config.page = page;
     
        // hide rows not on current page and show the rows that are
        for (var i=0;i<trs.length;i++) {
            if (typeof trs[i]["data-display"] == "undefined") {
                trs[i]["data-display"] = trs[i].style.display||"";
            }
            if (rows_per_page > 0) {
                if (i < page*rows_per_page && i >= (page-1)*rows_per_page) {
                    trs[i].style.display = trs[i]["data-display"];
                } else {
                    // Only hide if pagination is not disabled
                    if (!config.disable) {
                        trs[i].style.display = "none";
                    } else {
                        trs[i].style.display = trs[i]["data-display"];
                    }
                }
            } else {
                trs[i].style.display = trs[i]["data-display"];
            }
        }
    
        // page button maker functions
        config.active_class = config.active_class||"active";
        if (typeof config.box_mode != "function" && config.box_mode != "list" && config.box_mode != "buttons") {
            config.box_mode = "button";
        }
        if (typeof config.box_mode == "function") {
            config.box_mode(config);
        } else {
            var make_button;
            if (config.box_mode == "list") {
                make_button = function (symbol, index, config, disabled, active) {
                    var li = document.createElement("li");
                    var a  = document.createElement("a");
                    a.href = "#";
                    a.innerHTML = symbol;
                    a.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        this.parentNode.click();
                        return false;
                    }, false);
                    li.appendChild(a);
    
                    var classes = [];
                    if (disabled) {
                        classes.push("disabled");
                    }
                    if (active) {
                        classes.push(config.active_class);
                    }
                    li.className = classes.join(" ");
                    li.addEventListener("click", function () {
                        if (this.className.split(" ").indexOf("disabled") == -1) {
                            config.page = index;
                            _tableCustomFun.paginator(config);
                        }
                    }, false);
                    return li;
                }
            } else {
                make_button = function (symbol, index, config, disabled, active) {
                    var button = document.createElement("button");
                    button.innerHTML = symbol;
                    button.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        if (this.disabled != true) {
                            config.page = index;
                            _tableCustomFun.paginator(config);
                        }
                        return false;
                    }, false);
                    if (disabled) {
                        button.disabled = true;
                    }
                    if (active) {
                        button.className = config.active_class;
                    }
                    return button;
                }
            }
    
            // make page button collection
            var page_box = document.createElement(config.box_mode == "list"?"ul":"div");
            if (config.box_mode == "list") {
                page_box.className = "pagination";
            }
    
            var left = make_button("&laquo;", (page>1?page-1:1), config, (page == 1), false);
            page_box.appendChild(left);
    
            for (var i=1;i<=pages;i++) {
                var li = make_button(i, i, config, false, (page == i));
                page_box.appendChild(li);
            }
    
            var right = make_button("&raquo;", (pages>page?page+1:page), config, (page == pages), false);
            page_box.appendChild(right);
            if (box.childNodes.length) {
                while (box.childNodes.length > 1) {
                    box.removeChild(box.childNodes[0]);
                }
                box.replaceChild(page_box, box.childNodes[0]);
            } else {
                box.appendChild(page_box);
            }
        }
    
        // make rows per page selector
        if (!(typeof config.page_options == "boolean" && !config.page_options)) {
            if (typeof config.page_options == "undefined") {
                config.page_options = [
                    { value: 10, text: '10'  },
                    { value: 20, text: '20'  },
                    { value: 50, text: '50'  },
                    { value: 100,text: '100' },
                    { value: 0,  text: 'All' }
                ];
            }
            var options = config.page_options;
            var select = document.createElement("select");
            for (var i=0;i<options.length;i++) {
                var o = document.createElement("option");
                o.value = options[i].value;
                o.text = options[i].text;
                select.appendChild(o);
            }
            select.value = rows_per_page;
            select.addEventListener("change", function () {
                config.rows_per_page = this.value;
                _tableCustomFun.paginator(config);
            }, false);
            box.appendChild(select);
        }
    
        // status message
        var stat = document.createElement("span");
        stat.innerHTML = "On page " + page + " of " + pages
            + ", showing rows " + (((page-1)*rows_per_page)+1)
            + " to " + (trs.length<page*rows_per_page||rows_per_page==0?trs.length:page*rows_per_page)
            + " of " + trs.length;
        box.appendChild(stat);
    
        // hide pagination if disabled
        if (config.disable) {
            if (typeof box["data-display"] == "undefined") {
                box["data-display"] = box.style.display||"";
            }
            box.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            if (box.style.display == "none") {
                box.style.display = box["data-display"]||"";
            }
        }
    
        // run tail function
        if (typeof config.tail_call == "function") {
            config.tail_call(config);
        }
    
        return box;
    },
    sortTable: function(table, col, reverse) {
        
        _tableCustomFun.addShortingClass(table, col, reverse);
        var tb = table.tBodies[0], // use `<tbody>` to ignore `<thead>` and `<tfoot>` rows
            tr = Array.prototype.slice.call(tb.rows, 0), // put rows into array
            i;
        reverse = -((+reverse) || -1);
        tr = tr.sort(function (a, b) { // sort rows
            return reverse // `-1 *` if want opposite order
                * (a.cells[col].textContent.trim() // using `.textContent.trim()` for test
                    .localeCompare(b.cells[col].textContent.trim())
                   );
        });
        for(i = 0; i < tr.length; ++i) tb.appendChild(tr[i]); // append each row in order  
        
        
    },
    makeSortable: function(table) {
        var th = table.tHead, i;
        th && (th = th.rows[0]) && (th = th.cells);
        if (th) i = th.length;
        else return; // if no `<thead>` then do nothing
        while (--i >= 0) (function (i) {
            var dir = 1;
            th[i].addEventListener('click', function () {_tableCustomFun.sortTable(table, i, (dir = 1 - dir))});
        }(i));
    },
    makeAllSortable: function(parent) {
        parent = parent || document.body;
        var t = parent.getElementsByTagName('table'), i = t.length;
        while (--i >= 0) _tableCustomFun.makeSortable(t[i]);
    },
    addShortingClass: function(table, col, reverse){
        var thPosition = table.tHead.rows[0].cells[col];
        console.log(reverse);
        console.log(thPosition);
        var _thead = table.tHead.rows[0]
        
        for (var i = 0; i < _thead.cells.length; i++) {
            _thead.cells[i].removeAttribute("class");
        }
        thPosition.classList.add("shorting");
        if(reverse == 1){
            thPosition.classList.add("up");
        }else{
            thPosition.classList.add("down");
        }
    },
    init: function(){
        var tableNode = document.getElementById("table_box_native");
        if(tableNode){
            _tableCustomFun.addCssFile();
            _tableCustomFun.create_sample_table(document.getElementById("table_box_native"));
            _tableCustomFun.paginator({
                table: document.getElementById("table_box_native").getElementsByTagName("table")[0],
                box: document.getElementById("index_native"),
                active_class: "color_page"
            });
            _tableCustomFun.makeAllSortable();
        }
        
    },
    addCssFile: function(){
        var cssId = 'myCss';  // you could encode the css path itself to generate id..
        if (!document.getElementById(cssId))
        {
            var head  = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
            var link  = document.createElement('link');
            link.id   = cssId;
            link.rel  = 'stylesheet';
            link.type = 'text/css';
            link.href = 'css_tablecustom.cms?v=7&minify=1';
            link.media = 'all';
            head.appendChild(link);
        }
    }
}

// window.onload = function () {
//     _tableCustomFun.init();
// };
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){_tableCustomFun.init()})
```

```html
<div id="table_box_native" class="tableBox">
          
        </div>
        <div id="index_native" class="box tableDataBox"></div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi

Comment: Hi Friends i have find the answer of this . in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54881031/sorting-number-in-table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with `.localCompare`.

Following is the sample:

```js
function test(v1, v2) {
  console.log(v1.toString().localeCompare(v2.toString()))
}

test(1, 8)
test(1, 10)
test(8, 1)
test(8, 10) // This returns 1 instead of -1
test(10, 1)
test(10, 8)
```

Since you have numeric values,its always better to convert values to number and process it.

```
tr = tr.sort(function(a, b) { // sort rows
  var v1 = a.cells[col].textContent.trim();
  var v2 = b.cells[col].textContent.trim()
  return reverse * (v1 - v2);
});
```

**Sample:**

```js
myTableObjData = {
  'head': ['s.no', 'name', 'per%', 'price'],
  'body': [
    [1, 'rohit', '9%', 23],
    [10, 'rohit azad', '19%', 230],
    [8, 'rohit', '39%', 111],
  ]
}


var _tableCustomFun = {
  create_sample_table: function(parentNode, head, body, foot, data) {
    if (typeof head == "undefined") {
      head = true;
    }
    if (typeof body == "undefined") {
      body = true;
    }
    if (typeof foot == "undefined") {
      foot = true;
    }
    data = myTableObjData;

    var table = document.createElement("table");
    var tr, th, td;
    // header
    tr = document.createElement("tr");
    var headers = data.head || [];
    for (var i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
      th = document.createElement("th");
      span = document.createElement("span");
      span.innerHTML = headers[i];
      th.appendChild(span);
      tr.appendChild(th);
    }
    if (head) {
      var thead = document.createElement("thead");
      thead.appendChild(tr);
      table.appendChild(thead);
    } else {
      table.appendChild(tr);
    }
    // end header

    // body
    var table_body = data.body || [];
    if (body) {
      var tbody = document.createElement("tbody");
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < table_body.length; i++) {
      tr = document.createElement("tr");
      for (var j = 0; j < table_body[i].length; j++) {
        td = document.createElement("td");
        td.innerHTML = table_body[i][j];
        tr.appendChild(td);
      }
      if (body) {
        tbody.appendChild(tr);
      } else {
        table.appendChild(tr);
      }
    }
    if (body) {
      table.appendChild(tbody);
    }
    // end body

    if (parentNode) {
      parentNode.innerHTML = "";
      parentNode.appendChild(table);
    }
    //return table;
  },
  paginator: function(config) {
    // throw errors if insufficient parameters were given
    if (typeof config != "object")
      throw "Paginator was expecting a config object!";
    if (typeof config.get_rows != "function" && !(config.table instanceof Element))
      throw "Paginator was expecting a table or get_row function!";

    // get/set if things are disabled
    if (typeof config.disable == "undefined") {
      config.disable = false;
    }

    // get/make an element for storing the page numbers in
    var box;
    if (!(config.box instanceof Element)) {
      config.box = document.createElement("div");
    }
    box = config.box;

    // get/make function for getting table's rows
    if (typeof config.get_rows != "function") {
      config.get_rows = function() {
        var table = config.table
        var tbody = table.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0] || table;

        // get all the possible rows for paging
        // exclude any rows that are just headers or empty
        children = tbody.children;
        var trs = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
          if (children[i].nodeType = "tr") {
            if (children[i].getElementsByTagName("td").length > 0) {
              trs.push(children[i]);
            }
          }
        }

        return trs;
      }
    }
    var get_rows = config.get_rows;
    var trs = get_rows();

    // get/set rows per page
    if (typeof config.rows_per_page == "undefined") {
      var selects = box.getElementsByTagName("select");
      if (typeof selects != "undefined" && (selects.length > 0 && typeof selects[0].selectedIndex != "undefined")) {
        config.rows_per_page = selects[0].options[selects[0].selectedIndex].value;
      } else {
        config.rows_per_page = 150;
      }
    }
    var rows_per_page = config.rows_per_page;

    // get/set current page
    if (typeof config.page == "undefined") {
      config.page = 1;
    }
    var page = config.page;

    // get page count
    var pages = (rows_per_page > 0) ? Math.ceil(trs.length / rows_per_page) : 1;

    // check that page and page count are sensible values
    if (pages < 1) {
      pages = 1;
    }
    if (page > pages) {
      page = pages;
    }
    if (page < 1) {
      page = 1;
    }
    config.page = page;

    // hide rows not on current page and show the rows that are
    for (var i = 0; i < trs.length; i++) {
      if (typeof trs[i]["data-display"] == "undefined") {
        trs[i]["data-display"] = trs[i].style.display || "";
      }
      if (rows_per_page > 0) {
        if (i < page * rows_per_page && i >= (page - 1) * rows_per_page) {
          trs[i].style.display = trs[i]["data-display"];
        } else {
          // Only hide if pagination is not disabled
          if (!config.disable) {
            trs[i].style.display = "none";
          } else {
            trs[i].style.display = trs[i]["data-display"];
          }
        }
      } else {
        trs[i].style.display = trs[i]["data-display"];
      }
    }

    // page button maker functions
    config.active_class = config.active_class || "active";
    if (typeof config.box_mode != "function" && config.box_mode != "list" && config.box_mode != "buttons") {
      config.box_mode = "button";
    }
    if (typeof config.box_mode == "function") {
      config.box_mode(config);
    } else {
      var make_button;
      if (config.box_mode == "list") {
        make_button = function(symbol, index, config, disabled, active) {
          var li = document.createElement("li");
          var a = document.createElement("a");
          a.href = "#";
          a.innerHTML = symbol;
          a.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            this.parentNode.click();
            return false;
          }, false);
          li.appendChild(a);

          var classes = [];
          if (disabled) {
            classes.push("disabled");
          }
          if (active) {
            classes.push(config.active_class);
          }
          li.className = classes.join(" ");
          li.addEventListener("click", function() {
            if (this.className.split(" ").indexOf("disabled") == -1) {
              config.page = index;
              _tableCustomFun.paginator(config);
            }
          }, false);
          return li;
        }
      } else {
        make_button = function(symbol, index, config, disabled, active) {
          var button = document.createElement("button");
          button.innerHTML = symbol;
          button.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            if (this.disabled != true) {
              config.page = index;
              _tableCustomFun.paginator(config);
            }
            return false;
          }, false);
          if (disabled) {
            button.disabled = true;
          }
          if (active) {
            button.className = config.active_class;
          }
          return button;
        }
      }

      // make page button collection
      var page_box = document.createElement(config.box_mode == "list" ? "ul" : "div");
      if (config.box_mode == "list") {
        page_box.className = "pagination";
      }

      var left = make_button("&laquo;", (page > 1 ? page - 1 : 1), config, (page == 1), false);
      page_box.appendChild(left);

      for (var i = 1; i <= pages; i++) {
        var li = make_button(i, i, config, false, (page == i));
        page_box.appendChild(li);
      }

      var right = make_button("&raquo;", (pages > page ? page + 1 : page), config, (page == pages), false);
      page_box.appendChild(right);
      if (box.childNodes.length) {
        while (box.childNodes.length > 1) {
          box.removeChild(box.childNodes[0]);
        }
        box.replaceChild(page_box, box.childNodes[0]);
      } else {
        box.appendChild(page_box);
      }
    }

    // make rows per page selector
    if (!(typeof config.page_options == "boolean" && !config.page_options)) {
      if (typeof config.page_options == "undefined") {
        config.page_options = [{
            value: 10,
            text: '10'
          },
          {
            value: 20,
            text: '20'
          },
          {
            value: 50,
            text: '50'
          },
          {
            value: 100,
            text: '100'
          },
          {
            value: 0,
            text: 'All'
          }
        ];
      }
      var options = config.page_options;
      var select = document.createElement("select");
      for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        var o = document.createElement("option");
        o.value = options[i].value;
        o.text = options[i].text;
        select.appendChild(o);
      }
      select.value = rows_per_page;
      select.addEventListener("change", function() {
        config.rows_per_page = this.value;
        _tableCustomFun.paginator(config);
      }, false);
      box.appendChild(select);
    }

    // status message
    var stat = document.createElement("span");
    stat.innerHTML = "On page " + page + " of " + pages +
      ", showing rows " + (((page - 1) * rows_per_page) + 1) +
      " to " + (trs.length < page * rows_per_page || rows_per_page == 0 ? trs.length : page * rows_per_page) +
      " of " + trs.length;
    box.appendChild(stat);

    // hide pagination if disabled
    if (config.disable) {
      if (typeof box["data-display"] == "undefined") {
        box["data-display"] = box.style.display || "";
      }
      box.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      if (box.style.display == "none") {
        box.style.display = box["data-display"] || "";
      }
    }

    // run tail function
    if (typeof config.tail_call == "function") {
      config.tail_call(config);
    }

    return box;
  },
  sortTable: function(table, col, reverse) {

    _tableCustomFun.addShortingClass(table, col, reverse);
    var tb = table.tBodies[0], // use `<tbody>` to ignore `<thead>` and `<tfoot>` rows
      tr = Array.prototype.slice.call(tb.rows, 0), // put rows into array
      i;
    reverse = -((+reverse) || -1);
    tr = tr.sort(function(a, b) { // sort rows
      var v1 = a.cells[col].textContent.trim();
      var v2 = b.cells[col].textContent.trim()
      return reverse * (v1 - v2 );
    });
    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; ++i) tb.appendChild(tr[i]); // append each row in order  


  },
  makeSortable: function(table) {
    var th = table.tHead,
      i;
    th && (th = th.rows[0]) && (th = th.cells);
    if (th) i = th.length;
    else return; // if no `<thead>` then do nothing
    while (--i >= 0)(function(i) {
      var dir = 1;
      th[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        _tableCustomFun.sortTable(table, i, (dir = 1 - dir))
      });
    }(i));
  },
  makeAllSortable: function(parent) {
    parent = parent || document.body;
    var t = parent.getElementsByTagName('table'),
      i = t.length;
    while (--i >= 0) _tableCustomFun.makeSortable(t[i]);
  },
  addShortingClass: function(table, col, reverse) {
    var thPosition = table.tHead.rows[0].cells[col];
    console.log(reverse);
    console.log(thPosition);
    var _thead = table.tHead.rows[0]

    for (var i = 0; i < _thead.cells.length; i++) {
      _thead.cells[i].removeAttribute("class");
    }
    thPosition.classList.add("shorting");
    if (reverse == 1) {
      thPosition.classList.add("up");
    } else {
      thPosition.classList.add("down");
    }
  },
  init: function() {
    var tableNode = document.getElementById("table_box_native");
    if (tableNode) {
      _tableCustomFun.addCssFile();
      _tableCustomFun.create_sample_table(document.getElementById("table_box_native"));
      _tableCustomFun.paginator({
        table: document.getElementById("table_box_native").getElementsByTagName("table")[0],
        box: document.getElementById("index_native"),
        active_class: "color_page"
      });
      _tableCustomFun.makeAllSortable();
    }

  },
  addCssFile: function() {
    var cssId = 'myCss'; // you could encode the css path itself to generate id..
    if (!document.getElementById(cssId)) {
      var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
      var link = document.createElement('link');
      link.id = cssId;
      link.rel = 'stylesheet';
      link.type = 'text/css';
      link.href = 'css_tablecustom.cms?v=7&minify=1';
      link.media = 'all';
      head.appendChild(link);
    }
  }
}

// window.onload = function () {
//     _tableCustomFun.init();
// };
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  _tableCustomFun.init()
})
```

```html
<div id="table_box_native" class="tableBox">

</div>
<div id="index_native" class="box tableDataBox"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to sort the table based on columns data type (number and string). You can do so by checking the column *index*:

```
.......
tr = tr.sort(function (a, b) { // sort rows
     if(col == 0 || col == 3){
       return reverse * (+a.cells[col].textContent.trim() - +b.cells[col].textContent.trim());
     }
     else{
       return reverse // `-1 *` if want opposite order
       * (a.cells[col].textContent.trim() // using `.textContent.trim()` for test
          .localeCompare(b.cells[col].textContent.trim())
       );
    }
 });
 ........
```

```js
myTableObjData = {
  'head':['s.no', 'name', 'per%', 'price'],
  'body': [
          [1,'rohit', '9%', 23],
          [10,'rohit azad', '19%', 230],
          [8,'rohit', '39%', 111],
      ]
}


var _tableCustomFun = {
    create_sample_table: function(parentNode, head, body, foot, data) {
        if (typeof head == "undefined") {head = true;}
        if (typeof body == "undefined") {body = true;}
        if (typeof foot == "undefined") {foot = true;}
        data = myTableObjData;
        
        var table = document.createElement("table");
        var tr, th, td;
        // header
        tr = document.createElement("tr");
        var headers = data.head || [];
        for (var i=0;i<headers.length;i++) {
            th = document.createElement("th");
            span = document.createElement("span");
            span.innerHTML = headers[i];
            th.appendChild(span);
            tr.appendChild(th);
        }
        if (head) {
            var thead = document.createElement("thead");
            thead.appendChild(tr);
            table.appendChild(thead);
        } else {
            table.appendChild(tr);
        }
        // end header
    
        // body
        var table_body = data.body || [];
        if (body) {
            var tbody = document.createElement("tbody");
        }
        for (var i=0;i<table_body.length;i++) {
            tr = document.createElement("tr");
            for (var j=0;j<table_body[i].length;j++) {
                td = document.createElement("td");
                td.innerHTML = table_body[i][j];
                tr.appendChild(td);
            }
            if (body) {
                tbody.appendChild(tr);
            } else {
                table.appendChild(tr);
            }
        }
        if (body) {
            table.appendChild(tbody);
        }
        // end body
    
        if (parentNode) {
            parentNode.innerHTML = "";
            parentNode.appendChild(table);
        }
        //return table;
    },
    paginator: function(config) {
        // throw errors if insufficient parameters were given
        if (typeof config != "object")
            throw "Paginator was expecting a config object!";
        if (typeof config.get_rows != "function" && !(config.table instanceof Element))
            throw "Paginator was expecting a table or get_row function!";
    
        // get/set if things are disabled
        if (typeof config.disable == "undefined") {
            config.disable = false;
        }
    
        // get/make an element for storing the page numbers in
        var box;
        if (!(config.box instanceof Element)) {
            config.box = document.createElement("div");
        }
        box = config.box;
    
        // get/make function for getting table's rows
        if (typeof config.get_rows != "function") {
            config.get_rows = function () {
                var table = config.table
                var tbody = table.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0]||table;
    
                // get all the possible rows for paging
                // exclude any rows that are just headers or empty
                children = tbody.children;
                var trs = [];
                for (var i=0;i<children.length;i++) {
                    if (children[i].nodeType = "tr") {
                        if (children[i].getElementsByTagName("td").length > 0) {
                            trs.push(children[i]);
                        }
                    }
                }
    
                return trs;
            }
        }
        var get_rows = config.get_rows;
        var trs = get_rows();
    
        // get/set rows per page
        if (typeof config.rows_per_page == "undefined") {
            var selects = box.getElementsByTagName("select");
            if (typeof selects != "undefined" && (selects.length > 0 && typeof selects[0].selectedIndex != "undefined")) {
                config.rows_per_page = selects[0].options[selects[0].selectedIndex].value;
            } else {
                config.rows_per_page = 150;
            }
        }
        var rows_per_page = config.rows_per_page;
    
        // get/set current page
        if (typeof config.page == "undefined") {
            config.page = 1;
        }
        var page = config.page;
    
        // get page count
        var pages = (rows_per_page > 0)? Math.ceil(trs.length / rows_per_page):1;
    
        // check that page and page count are sensible values
        if (pages < 1) {
            pages = 1;
        }
        if (page > pages) {
            page = pages;
        }
        if (page < 1) {
            page = 1;
        }
        config.page = page;
     
        // hide rows not on current page and show the rows that are
        for (var i=0;i<trs.length;i++) {
            if (typeof trs[i]["data-display"] == "undefined") {
                trs[i]["data-display"] = trs[i].style.display||"";
            }
            if (rows_per_page > 0) {
                if (i < page*rows_per_page && i >= (page-1)*rows_per_page) {
                    trs[i].style.display = trs[i]["data-display"];
                } else {
                    // Only hide if pagination is not disabled
                    if (!config.disable) {
                        trs[i].style.display = "none";
                    } else {
                        trs[i].style.display = trs[i]["data-display"];
                    }
                }
            } else {
                trs[i].style.display = trs[i]["data-display"];
            }
        }
    
        // page button maker functions
        config.active_class = config.active_class||"active";
        if (typeof config.box_mode != "function" && config.box_mode != "list" && config.box_mode != "buttons") {
            config.box_mode = "button";
        }
        if (typeof config.box_mode == "function") {
            config.box_mode(config);
        } else {
            var make_button;
            if (config.box_mode == "list") {
                make_button = function (symbol, index, config, disabled, active) {
                    var li = document.createElement("li");
                    var a  = document.createElement("a");
                    a.href = "#";
                    a.innerHTML = symbol;
                    a.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        this.parentNode.click();
                        return false;
                    }, false);
                    li.appendChild(a);
    
                    var classes = [];
                    if (disabled) {
                        classes.push("disabled");
                    }
                    if (active) {
                        classes.push(config.active_class);
                    }
                    li.className = classes.join(" ");
                    li.addEventListener("click", function () {
                        if (this.className.split(" ").indexOf("disabled") == -1) {
                            config.page = index;
                            _tableCustomFun.paginator(config);
                        }
                    }, false);
                    return li;
                }
            } else {
                make_button = function (symbol, index, config, disabled, active) {
                    var button = document.createElement("button");
                    button.innerHTML = symbol;
                    button.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        if (this.disabled != true) {
                            config.page = index;
                            _tableCustomFun.paginator(config);
                        }
                        return false;
                    }, false);
                    if (disabled) {
                        button.disabled = true;
                    }
                    if (active) {
                        button.className = config.active_class;
                    }
                    return button;
                }
            }
    
            // make page button collection
            var page_box = document.createElement(config.box_mode == "list"?"ul":"div");
            if (config.box_mode == "list") {
                page_box.className = "pagination";
            }
    
            var left = make_button("&laquo;", (page>1?page-1:1), config, (page == 1), false);
            page_box.appendChild(left);
    
            for (var i=1;i<=pages;i++) {
                var li = make_button(i, i, config, false, (page == i));
                page_box.appendChild(li);
            }
    
            var right = make_button("&raquo;", (pages>page?page+1:page), config, (page == pages), false);
            page_box.appendChild(right);
            if (box.childNodes.length) {
                while (box.childNodes.length > 1) {
                    box.removeChild(box.childNodes[0]);
                }
                box.replaceChild(page_box, box.childNodes[0]);
            } else {
                box.appendChild(page_box);
            }
        }
    
        // make rows per page selector
        if (!(typeof config.page_options == "boolean" && !config.page_options)) {
            if (typeof config.page_options == "undefined") {
                config.page_options = [
                    { value: 10, text: '10'  },
                    { value: 20, text: '20'  },
                    { value: 50, text: '50'  },
                    { value: 100,text: '100' },
                    { value: 0,  text: 'All' }
                ];
            }
            var options = config.page_options;
            var select = document.createElement("select");
            for (var i=0;i<options.length;i++) {
                var o = document.createElement("option");
                o.value = options[i].value;
                o.text = options[i].text;
                select.appendChild(o);
            }
            select.value = rows_per_page;
            select.addEventListener("change", function () {
                config.rows_per_page = this.value;
                _tableCustomFun.paginator(config);
            }, false);
            box.appendChild(select);
        }
    
        // status message
        var stat = document.createElement("span");
        stat.innerHTML = "On page " + page + " of " + pages
            + ", showing rows " + (((page-1)*rows_per_page)+1)
            + " to " + (trs.length<page*rows_per_page||rows_per_page==0?trs.length:page*rows_per_page)
            + " of " + trs.length;
        box.appendChild(stat);
    
        // hide pagination if disabled
        if (config.disable) {
            if (typeof box["data-display"] == "undefined") {
                box["data-display"] = box.style.display||"";
            }
            box.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            if (box.style.display == "none") {
                box.style.display = box["data-display"]||"";
            }
        }
    
        // run tail function
        if (typeof config.tail_call == "function") {
            config.tail_call(config);
        }
    
        return box;
    },
    sortTable: function(table, col, reverse) {
        
        _tableCustomFun.addShortingClass(table, col, reverse);
        var tb = table.tBodies[0], // use `<tbody>` to ignore `<thead>` and `<tfoot>` rows
            tr = Array.prototype.slice.call(tb.rows, 0), // put rows into array
            i;
        reverse = -((+reverse) || -1);
        tr = tr.sort(function (a, b) { // sort rows
            if(col == 0 || col == 3){
              return reverse * (+a.cells[col].textContent.trim() - +b.cells[col].textContent.trim());
            }
            else{
              return reverse // `-1 *` if want opposite order
              * (a.cells[col].textContent.trim() // using `.textContent.trim()` for test
              .localeCompare(b.cells[col].textContent.trim())
              );
           }
        });
        for(i = 0; i < tr.length; ++i) tb.appendChild(tr[i]); // append each row in order  
        
        
    },
    makeSortable: function(table) {
        var th = table.tHead, i;
        th && (th = th.rows[0]) && (th = th.cells);
        if (th) i = th.length;
        else return; // if no `<thead>` then do nothing
        while (--i >= 0) (function (i) {
            var dir = 1;
            th[i].addEventListener('click', function () {_tableCustomFun.sortTable(table, i, (dir = 1 - dir))});
        }(i));
    },
    makeAllSortable: function(parent) {
        parent = parent || document.body;
        var t = parent.getElementsByTagName('table'), i = t.length;
        while (--i >= 0) _tableCustomFun.makeSortable(t[i]);
    },
    addShortingClass: function(table, col, reverse){
        var thPosition = table.tHead.rows[0].cells[col];
        //console.log(reverse);
        //console.log(thPosition);
        var _thead = table.tHead.rows[0]
        
        for (var i = 0; i < _thead.cells.length; i++) {
            _thead.cells[i].removeAttribute("class");
        }
        thPosition.classList.add("shorting");
        if(reverse == 1){
            thPosition.classList.add("up");
        }else{
            thPosition.classList.add("down");
        }
    },
    init: function(){
        var tableNode = document.getElementById("table_box_native");
        if(tableNode){
            _tableCustomFun.addCssFile();
            _tableCustomFun.create_sample_table(document.getElementById("table_box_native"));
            _tableCustomFun.paginator({
                table: document.getElementById("table_box_native").getElementsByTagName("table")[0],
                box: document.getElementById("index_native"),
                active_class: "color_page"
            });
            _tableCustomFun.makeAllSortable();
        }
        
    },
    addCssFile: function(){
        var cssId = 'myCss';  // you could encode the css path itself to generate id..
        if (!document.getElementById(cssId))
        {
            var head  = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
            var link  = document.createElement('link');
            link.id   = cssId;
            link.rel  = 'stylesheet';
            link.type = 'text/css';
            link.href = 'css_tablecustom.cms?v=7&minify=1';
            link.media = 'all';
            head.appendChild(link);
        }
    }
}

// window.onload = function () {
//     _tableCustomFun.init();
// };
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){_tableCustomFun.init()})
```

```html
<div id="table_box_native" class="tableBox">

</div>
<div id="index_native" class="box tableDataBox"></div>
```

Comment: Minor pointer, OP's code is huge. Better to cherry-pick your changes and highlight them. I did the same.